# same package, different level based on appender type

Tags: logback, spring-logback

I have many packages and i need to log into a file only the warning level for a specific package. But i need, in the console appender, to continue seeing the `INFO` level also for that package.

Here is my try in the `logback.xml` but the result is that i correctly see all the level logs in the console but, for the specific package, into the file are logged the `INFO` level too while i need only the `WARN` Level.

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="my_file_appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>myLog.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT_2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!--  root logger for all packages  -->

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
    
    <!--  file logger for specific package  -->

    <logger name="com.trenolab.treno4.railml">
        <level value="WARN" />
        <appender-ref ref="my_file_appender" />
    </logger>
    
    <!--  console logger for specific package  -->

    <logger name="com.trenolab.treno4.railml" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT_2" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```